# my setState only toggles once

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm using a setState to toggle the view of a popup (modal from [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) a bootstrap library for ReactJS). When I run the component the popup is shown as intended and if I close it it will disappear as intended. If the component is called again it won't update the state and so it won't render de popup again. Only if i refresh the page again.

One of the three pop up child components:

```
export class MatchPopup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        modal: false,
      };
      this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      this.toggle()
    }
    toggle() {
      this.setState({
        modal: !this.state.modal
      });
      console.log(this.state.modal)
    }
    render() {
       <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
       </Modal>
    }
}
```

In my parent component this is the function to render the popup component.

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {      
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            match: this.props.match,
            token: this.props.token,
            popup: '',
            statusIcon: ''
        };
    }

matched(){
    this.setState({popup: <MatchPopup showAlert={this.props.showAlert} match={this.props.match} token={this.props.token}/>})
}

challenged(){
    this.setState({popup: <ChallengedPopup showAlert={this.props.showAlert} match={this.props.match} token={this.props.token}/>})
}

accepted(){
    this.setState({popup: <AcceptedPopup showAlert={this.props.showAlert} match={this.props.match} photo_url_hd={this.props.photo_url_hd} token={this.props.token}/>})
}

componentDidMount(){ 
    // pop up to challenge someone this is the child component that i mentioned
    if(this.props.match.challenged == 0){
        this.setState({statusIcon:<div tabIndex="1" className="challengeButton" onClick={() => this.matched()}><div className="Paperplane"><FaPaperPlane /></div></div>})
    } 
    // pop up if someone challenges you
    if(this.props.match.challenged != 0 && this.props.match.challenged != 3 && this.props.match.userBeingChallenged == 1 ){
        this.setState({statusIcon: <div tabIndex="1" className="challengeButton" onClick={() => this.challenged()}><div className="Envelope"><FaEnvelope /></div></div>})
    } 
    //you have challenged someone
    if(this.props.match.challenged != 0 && this.props.match.challenged != 3 && this.props.match.userBeingChallenged == 0){
        this.setState({statusIcon:<div tabIndex="1" className="challengeButtonDisabled"><div className="paperplaneDisabled"><FaPaperPlane /></div></div>})
    } 
    //match is accepted
    if(this.props.match.challenged == 3){
        this.setState({statusIcon:<div tabIndex="1" className="challengeButton" onClick={() => this.accepted()}><div className="Rocket"><FaRocket /></div></div>})
    }
}

render() 
{       
var popup = this.state.popup

return  (
        <div className="...">
            <div className="..."><img className="friendPic" src={this.props.match.friend.photo_url}/>{this.state.statusIcon}{popup}</div>
                <p className="...">{this.props.match.friend.name}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `matched` function in the parent is getting called?

Comment: yes i am sure: onClick={() => this.matched()}

Comment: Are you doing `this.match = this.match.bind(this);` in the parent component?

Comment: Also... are you storing components inside the state? Why?

Comment: Is `var popup = this.state.popup` outside of `render` in parent component ?

Comment: I have updated my post with a more complete preview of the parent component. I hope this will answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

When setting state based on the current state you should use the functional callback version of `setState`

```
toggle() {
  this.setState(state => ({
    modal: !state.modal
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however this does not seem to work. If i log my actions: on page load the state is false, if i open it it's true, if i close it it's false and when i want to open it again it remains false so it won't open.